# How to change fields brought back by Content search?

Tags: content, content-search

I created a custom field on Content, but when someone searches Content I want the field to display on the table display.  Any idea how to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display options are predefined, you cannot add custom fields unfortunately.

Vote it up : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqFvAAK

Comment: Upvoted the idea... but don't have much faith in it.  That idea was created 6 years ago :(

Comment: no kidding - it was my idea! we were an early adopter of Content